# Category Page in Mangeto 1.9 not showing SSL. Rest all pages including home page & product page are working fine

Tags: php, magento, ssl, magento-1.9

I have this strange issue on my website colourvape.com. As you can see its showing https secure on https://www.colourvape.com/ and its product page but it's not showing the same on the category pages like https://www.colourvape.com/cartomizer.html.

I have google a lot but cannot find a similar issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to show secure ssl on my category page too.

Comment: some of your images are getting loaded over HTTP. That's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your category page has mixed content.

[image]

From [Google Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content):

> Mixed content occurs when initial HTML is loaded over a secure HTTPS connection, but other resources (such as images, videos, stylesheets, scripts) are loaded over an insecure HTTP connection. This is called mixed content because both HTTP and HTTPS content are being loaded to display the same page, and the initial request was secure over HTTPS. Modern browsers display warnings about this type of content to indicate to the user that this page contains insecure resources.

You need to load the images from an HTTPS source too.

If you still couldn't find which image is getting loaded over HTTP, I have found one but there can be more

```
http://www.colourvape.com/media/wysiwyg/sliderimg/offer.jpg
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. I changed those http images links to https. Now its working.